# Gobblin job metrics not publishing data to InfluxDB

Tags: java, influxdb, data-ingestion, gobblin

I have configured .pull file to produce and send metrics to InfluxDb for source, extractor and converter jobs. I tried with the example wikipedia job.

```
metrics.enabled=true
metrics.report.interval=30000
metrics.reporting.influxdb.metrics.enabled=true
metrics.reporting.influxdb.events.enabled=true
metrics.reporting.influxdb.database=****
metrics.reporting.influxdb.url=http://**.**.**.**:8086
metrics.reporting.influxdb.user=********
metrics.reporting.influxdb.password=****
metrics.reporting.influxdb.sending.type=TCP
```

But the job is not sending any data. I could not find any example with metrics in Gobblin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem here. The gobblin uses config file as a source for metrics configuration. Instead of adding the properties to *.pull or *.job file, I had to add those to *.conf file.
Once added, it will send metrics to the platform whichever is addded to the gobblin application.